# Java newbie needing advice on how to show buttons moving

Tags: java, loops, jbutton

I am attempting to make a button move across the screen when text is entered into a text screen, Ive come up with this code but it ends up just showing the end location when I actually want to see it moving:

```
if (TextDemo.textField.getText().equals("moveCar"))
    {

        for (int x = 0; x<250;x++)
        {

            try
            {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            }catch
            (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }   
            jOneCarOne.setLocation(130 + x, 210);
            }                                   
    }
```

I did have a repaint method in there but it made no difference, Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you familiar with and/or running this in the event dispatch thread?

Comment: I am not no :( only just started learning Java a couple of days a go so my knowledge is shamefully limited

Comment: Read up on it. Not sure if it's your problem but you should run all GUI Swing code from this thread

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
public class TextDemo {
    static JFrame frame;
    static JTextField textField;
    static Component jOneCarOne;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(0, 0, 640, 20);
        textField.addActionListener(getTextFieldAction());
        frame.add(textField);

        jOneCarOne = new JLabel("<html><b><u>CAR");
        jOneCarOne.setBounds(130, 210, 64, 64);
        frame.add(jOneCarOne);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static ActionListener getTextFieldAction() {
        return new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (TextDemo.textField.getText().equals("moveCar")) {
                    moveCar();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    static void moveCar() {
        final int endX = jOneCarOne.getX() + 250;
        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            //execute this every 10 ms
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(jOneCarOne.getX() == endX) {
                    //break condition, cancel periodic execution
                    this.cancel();
                }
                jOneCarOne.setLocation(jOneCarOne.getX() + 1, jOneCarOne.getY());
            }
        }, 0, 10);
    }
}
```